# How to exclude rows when using a LEFT JOIN (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, activerecord

I have **users** with many **posts**. I want to build an SQL query that would do the following in 1 query (no subquery), and hopefully no unions if possible. I know I can do this with union but I want to learn if this can be done using only joins.

**I want to get a list of distinct active users who:**

1. have no posts
2. have no approved posts

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN posts p
    ON p.user_id = u.id
  LEFT JOIN posts p2
    ON p2.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.status = 'active'
  AND (p.status IS NULL
  OR p2.status != 'approved');
```

The problem is when a user has multiple posts and one is active. This will still return the user which I do not want. If a user has an active post, he should be removed from the result set. Any ideas?

**Here's what the data looks like:**

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+---------+
| id | status  |
+----+---------+
|  1 | active  |
|  2 | pending |
|  3 | pending |
|  4 | active  |
|  5 | active  |
+----+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from posts;
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | status   |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 | approved |
|  2 |       1 | pending  |
|  3 |       4 | pending  |
+----+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The answer here should be only users 4 and 5. 4 doesn't have an approved post and 5 doesn't have a post. It should not include 1, which has an approved post.

Comment: Why are you joining`users` table with two instances of `posts` table?

Comment: With the first join, I'm trying to get all users with no posts, on the second one, I'm getting the ones which aren't approved. Which is wrong because this will still include users with multiple posts with one being approved.

Comment: "have no active posts" -> do you mean "have no *approved* posts"?

Comment: How many rows in each table?  (Huge tables need to take into account caching issues.)  What indexes do you have?  (Some of the proffered answers will be slow without appropriate index(es).)

Comment: @ChrisSalzberg thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your requirements and translating them literally to SQL, I get this:

```
SELECT users.id,
       COUNT(posts.id) as posts_count,
       COUNT(approved_posts.id) as approved_posts_count
FROM users
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN posts approved_posts
  ON approved_posts.status = 'approved'
  AND approved_posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.status = "active"
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING (posts_count = 0 OR approved_posts_count = 0);
```

For your test data above, this returns:

```
4|1|0
5|0|0
```

i.e. users with ids `4` and `5`, the first of which has 1 post but no approved posts and the second of which has no posts.

However, it seems to me that this can be simplified since *any user that has no approved posts will also have no posts*, so the union of conditions is unnecessary.

In that case, the SQL is simply:

```
SELECT users.id,
       COUNT(approved_posts.id) as approved_posts_count
FROM users
LEFT JOIN posts approved_posts
  ON approved_posts.status = 'approved'
  AND approved_posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.status = "active"
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING approved_posts_count = 0;
```

This also returns the same two users. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nice formulation.  You are 'missing' the necessary indexes.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer. It is very systematic and well explained. Thanks for this!

Comment: Thanks! Glad you found the answer useful.

Answer (score 4):

Not exists:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM posts p
   WHERE p.user_id = u.id AND p.status = 'approved');
```

Or equivalent LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN posts p
   ON p.user_id = u.id AND p.status = 'approved'
WHERE p.user_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I am hoping to avoid subqueries if possible.

Comment: Why avoid subquries? This is just the case for it. Ok, converted it to left join, see updated answer.

Comment: I will be chaining this query with different scopes and would like it to be as fast as possible. I'm also interested to learn if this could be done using only joins.

Comment: Ah!  It may actually be faster to use `EXISTS` when chaining!  You cannot necessarily optimize a query piecemeal.

Answer (score 1):

Please explain why you don't want JOINs or UNIONs.  If it is because of performance, then consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( PRIMARY KEY(user_id) )
    SELECT user_id, MIN(status) AS z
    FROM Posts
    GROUP BY user_id;

SELECT  u.id AS user,
        IFNULL(z, 'no_posts') AS status
    FROM users u
    WHERE u.status = 'active'
    LEFT JOIN t ON t.user_id = u.id
    HAVING status != 'approved';
```

It will make only one pass over each table, thereby being reasonably efficient (considering the complexity of the query).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid unions because of performance and I'm also interested to know if this can be done using only JOINS. This seems to be a common and simple problem so I'm thinking I might be missing something. Your solution uses another table (persisted instead of temp) though. Do you think a join-only solution is possible?

Comment: If performance is the real goal, I recommend you test each of the many answers, fix the typos, time them (run twice, and with `SQL_NO_CACHE`).  Then pick the fastest.  Better yet, do `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%'` to get a more precise feel for effort involved.  (This works even for small tables.)

Comment: "Correlated" subqueries can be rather costly; so can "derived" tables (`JOIN ( SELECT ... )`).  My temp table is also costly.

Comment: I've looked at thousands of forum questions; I don't recall seeing one quite like yours.  The answers show that there are many possible approaches.  Some aspects of yours are very common, but the combination is rare.

Comment: "How to do 'join-only'" is an academic question.  I assumed the real question is "how to do fastest".

Comment: Thank you very much for all the comments, they were really helpful. Now, I see that there are multiple solutions to the problem depending on what I actually need. Pardon me for being unclear, but yes, this is an academic question and I just wanted to learn if this could be done with a simple join.

Answer (score 1):

This one may help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN posts p ON 1=1
  -- matches only if user has any post
  AND p.user_id = u.id 
  -- matches only if user has any active post
  AND p.status = 'approved'
WHERE 1=1
  -- matches only active users
  AND u.status = 'active'
  -- matches only users with no matches on the LEFT JOIN
  AND p.status IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be easy.

```
SELECT u.`id`, u.`status` FROM `users` u
LEFT OUTER JOIN `post` p ON p.`user_id` = u.`id` AND p.`status` = 'approved'
WHERE u.`status` = 'active' AND p.`id` IS NULL
```

Gives a result of 4 & 5.

[Edit] Just wanted to add why this works:

> u.`status` = 'active'

This results into exclusion of all users that are not active.

> p.`status` = 'approved'

This excludes all posts that are approved.

Hence, by using these two lines, we have excluded all users that qualify as approved for your criteria.

[Edit 2]

If you also need to know how many pending and how many approved, here is an updated version:

```
SELECT u.`id`, u.`status`, SUM(IF(p.`status` = 'approved', 1, 0)) AS `Approved_Posts`, SUM(IF(p.`status` = 'pending', 1, 0)) AS `Pending_Posts`
FROM `test_users` u
LEFT OUTER JOIN `test_post` p ON p.`user_id` = u.`id`
WHERE u.`status` = 'active' 
GROUP BY u.`id`
HAVING SUM(IF(p.`id` IS NOT NULL, 1, 0))
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest answer. But I chose Chris's answer because I believe it will be more helpful for a wider set of problems.

Comment: I didn't know you needed the number of posts pending and approved as well. I modified the query further.

Also, note that 2 left joins is less efficient than 1 left join.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT u.*
    FROM users u
      LEFT JOIN posts p
        ON p.user_id = u.id
    WHERE 
        u.status = 'active' AND (
        p.user_id IS NULL
        OR p.status != 'approved');
```

**EDIT**

As per the updated question, the above query will include User 1. If we want to prevent that, and don't want to use inner query, we can use `group_concat` function of MySQL to get all the (distinct) statuses and see if it contains 'active' status, below query should give the desired output:

```
SELECT u.id, group_concat(distinct p.status) as statuses
    FROM users u
      LEFT JOIN posts p
        ON u.id = p.user_id
    WHERE 
        u.status = 'active'
group by u.id
having (statuses is null or statuses not like '%approved%');
```

Comment: is this a typo? WHERE p.user_id IS NULL

Comment: Nope, `p.user_id` will be null if there's no corresponding record in post table. It's to check whether user has any post at all.

Comment: hmm..this is actually a simplified version of what I have. I actually omitted another filter condition here for users, so the problem for me with this is that p.user_id IS NULL will return all those users with no posts. I've updated the question with the use case.

Comment: @gerky I have added another condition to check for user's status as well. Can you try now?

Comment: hm..still won't work, this will still return user 1 from my example which has 2 posts, 1 pending and 1 approved.

Comment: Note that `posts` needs `INDEX(user_id)`.

Comment: @gerky I have updated my answer with another solution. Can you please have a look?

Comment: ah..interesting answer, however, the wildcard match seems like it could be very slow? also seems a bit hacky

Comment: `HAVING` cannot use an index.  Yes, the wild cards will slow things down _some_.  The main cost in most queries is "fetching a row".

Comment: And the edit the simple reason why it could very possible not work.  If status is pending, and approved what is the likely status for when a post does not get approved.  Not approved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u LEFT JOIN posts p
    ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.status IS NULL 
  OR p.status != 'approved';
```

Comment: this won't get users with no posts since this is an inner join

Comment: this won't support the use case of a user having 2 posts, one pending and one approved.